# Broken wire connector

Tags: ac, clutch, wire

The plastic part of the plug that my ac clutch connects to is broken. I cant get it unplugged.  Im trying to change ac compressor in 04 kia sorento.  I need easiest way possible to fix this

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Do you have an image of the broken part? I'm trying to figure out what part of it is broken which is not allowing you to take it off.

Answer (score 1):

Cut the old one off and buy a new pigtail form the dealer and splice it into the wiring harness.